# find list of installed device drivers ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, drivers

How can I find out list of all device drivers installed in my ubuntu. I need list of device drivers not kernel drivers.

Comment: Have you tried running `Synaptic`? It lists all software installed. It should be installed by default, but if not, you can find it in the `software-center`.

Comment: It listed everything installed on ubuntu. I want on device drivers. Could I get that from Synaptic ?

Comment: yes. Synaptic lists everything - kernels, programs, drivers, etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Device drivers in Linux (and Ubuntu) are called "**kernel modules**". In fact, they are more than "device drivers" as they can provide functionality beyond serving the real hardware like creating virtual devices or providing new functionality for the kernel.

Use `lsmod` or `cat /proc/modules` commands to see the list of modules **loaded** into the kernel. To see all modules stored on the disk (not necessarily loaded), run:

```
ls -R /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/
```

All above concerns modules loaded from the disk. The Linux kernel also has built-in (or statically compiled) modules that aren't shown by the above commands. This is especially valid for embedded systems that are usually optimized by storage. You can list built-in modules using:

```
cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin
```

This command assumes your distro is providing `modules.builtin` file.